# Is is possible to import variables from a module for use with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

As a heads-up, I'm still learning the ins and outs of Python and I'm very new to Selenium.

I'm trying to see if it's possible to use variables from a .py file in a .py running Selenium.

For instance, let's say I have a file in a custom module, variables.py, that contains these variables:

```
username = 'string1'
passkey = 'string2'
```

and I want to import them into a Selenium instance and use them like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from [module] import variables
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("\path\login.html")
assert "Login Here" in driver.title

eleUserMessage = driver.find_element_by_id("user")
eleUserMessage.clear()
eleUserMessage.send_keys(username)
eleUserMessage = driver.find_element_by_id("pass")
eleUserMessage.clear()
eleUserMessage.send_keys(passkey)
```

Would that be possible at all???

Comment: Have your tried running it yourself?  Don't forget to pass the correct id (or xpath,..) and click button submit when it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. To use the variables, use the syntax `[module].variable_name`.

**Example**

```
# module.py
x = 6
y = "Hello"

# main.py
import module

print(module.x) # prints 6
print(module.y) # prints "Hello"
```

Comment: so using something like `eleUserMessage.send_keys(module.passkey)` would work?

Comment: Yes, it should.